# C# NullReference Exception even when object set to an instance

Tags: c#, instance, nullreferenceexception

I have encountered a really weird `NullReferenceException`. I have an object set to an instance using `new` keyword yet the exception still gets thrown. Here is the code I have:

Game Class

```
public class Game
{      
    public Game(Player playerParam) 
    {
        Player = playerParam;       
    }

    public Player Player;
    public int Duration = 60;
}

public class Player
{
   public Difficulty Difficulty;
   public string Name;
   public int Bonus;
}
```

Now I first create the Player instance then when the game starts I create game passing in the Player. This works as expected. But I have another class for Setting whose constructor takes in a Game object and accesses Player to change some setting. I do it like this:

```
public class Settings
{
    private Game game;
    public Settings(Game gameParam)
    {
        game = gameParam;
    }

    private void changeDifficulty(Difficulty difficulty)
    {
        game.Player.Difficulty = difficulty;
    }
}
```

The line

```
game.Player.Difficulty = difficulty;
```

throws the NullReferenceException even though I pass into Settings constructor, an already initialized Game object. Stepping into the code I find that the Game object (game) on settings is still null. Whats wrong here

Player is instantiated like this

```
Player player = new Player();
```

right above the constructor.

Here are additional details. 
I instantiate Player before Game and this is done on the main game Form. I then pass the instantiated values to Settings which is actually another WinForm. I step into the code and find game is instantiated when I pass it into Settings Form constructor. However on the Settings Form, Game object is null when accessed.

Comment: you left off the part where you instantiate game with a non-null player

Comment: You have to call the settings constructor before you change the diffuculty.

Comment: Can you show us your code that creates player, game, settings etc and how they are injected please.

Comment: Please show the code where you create the player. Should be something like `Player p = new Player;`

Comment: Are you sure you are instantiating player correctly? please show us more code

Comment: The code that you provided works great for me. Must be a problem in the rest of your code. Show it to us!

Comment: Here is how I instantiate Player
Player player = new Player();
It's only the Game object that I instantiate when I need it.

Comment: One thing to note is that on the Main Game Form, Player and Game aren't null as I have stepped into the code and ascertained this but when I move to the second Form, Settings, then I find Game is null.

Comment: @Dennis and you are sure that when you create `Settings` and pass it a non `null` `Game`, that `Game` has a non `null` `Player`?

Comment: Yes am sure about that. Infact I even decided to create the Game object on the line before passing it onto the Settings Form but stepping into the Settings Form, the Game object there was null

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that your `Player` is null which results in the null ref exception when you try to access the `Difficulty` property, not that `game` is null.

Comment: "Stepping into the code I find that the Game object (game) on settings is still null"

Comment: @bonyjoe -- Yeah, I saw that but I'm not entirely convinced of that given the lack of clarity of the question itself.

Comment: When my program runs for the first time, I create the Player object like this
Player player = new Player(); 
Its only the Game object that I create before starting a new Game.

Comment: @bonyjoe "Stepping into the code I find that the Game object (game) on settings is still null" has been added to the question long after this answer appeared.